# Change textbox to dropdown

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, infragistics

How can I change text box with a dropdown in Infragistics?

I have a reference to UltraGridCell myCell.

I see that there is a method for the cell but it doesn't work.

```
myCell.Style = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.ColumnStyle.DropDownList;
```

Do you know how can I handle this problem?

Comment: Have you assigned a value list to the cell or column?

Comment: I need to create a new dropdown with a new list, but I don;t know how to assign value list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to show the cell as a drop down you have to set its `ValueList` property and set the `Style` to `DropDown` or `DropDownList`.

You can create a value list with

```
var vl = new ValueList();
vl.ValueListItems.Add("Item 1");
vl.ValueListItems.Add("Item 2");
vl.ValueListItems.Add("Item 3");
```

and then set it to either the cell or the column, depending on whether it should be valid for all cells or just a particular one

```
myCell.ValueList = vl;
myColumn.ValueList = vl;
```

---

If you require the data value of the item to be different than the displayed text you can use the overload of `Add` that takes and object and a string, i.e.

```
vl.ValueListItems.Add(1234, "Item 1");
```

Then the displayed text would be `Item 1` but the value in the cell would be `1234`